# How to insert unicode text in IEEE paper?

Tags: xetex, pdftex, luatex, unicode

I am writing a paper for IEEE conference. I would like to know how to insert some unicode text into the paper. The primary language of the paper is English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it depends on the language of the text you use. But you should use XeTeX or luaTeX.

This is a minimal example from Wikipedia:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Linux Libertine O}
\begin{document}
\subsection{Ελληνικά}
Ὅλοι οἱ ἄνθρωποι γεννιοῦνται ἐλεύθεροι καὶ ἴσοι στὴν ἀξιοπρέπεια
καὶ τὰ δικαιώματα.

\end{document}
```

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XeTeX#Example